# MySQL Daemon failed to start - Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm'

Tags: mysqld

Fresh install of CentOS 6 on a test box, ran following as root:

```
yum install mysql-server    #success
service mysqld start        #success
service mysqld stop         #success
cd /var/lib/
cp -rp mysql mysql.bak      
rm -rf mysql                
cp -rp mysql.bak mysql      
service mysqld start
```

MySQL Daemon failed to start.

```
cat mysqld.log
```

/usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 4 mysql   mysql   4096 May  1 13:26 mysql
drwxr-xr-x. 4 mysql   mysql   4096 May  1 13:23 mysql.bak
```

Directories are the same

```
diff -r mysql mysql.bak
```

No differences

```
ls -lR mysql > out1
ls -lR mysql.bak > out2
diff out1 out2
```

No differences

I also looked manually and every file in mysql vs mysql.bak has the same ownership mysql:mysql & same permissions.

Ive seen the previous SO issue like this, but that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does ./mysql/plugin.frm exist?

Comment: Also, SELinux may be a problem: http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/11531-mysql-server-is-not-starting-after-xtrabackup-restore-using-innobackupex-tool

Comment: yes ./mysql/plugin.frm exists

Comment: yes SElinux was the answer, I disabled it and now things work.

Comment: @randymelder You can write that as an answer.

Comment: @ypercube done! thx

Answer (score 2):

The answer maybe in the question. "Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm'"

1. Make sure that file exists and permissions are correct, which you did.
2. Next, SELinux may interfering ([see this post](http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup/11531-mysql-server-is-not-starting-after-xtrabackup-restore-using-innobackupex-tool))

You may test the SELinux theory by running the following:

```
setenforce 0
service mysql start
```

To permanently turn off SELinux, follow the steps [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-turn-off-selinux/).